# Adding bdi tag to contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

im trying to add  tag to contenteditable when pressing space button in the contenteditable div.
problem is its just adding the bdi tag and i cant write inside it, so if i do:

```
    document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,'<bdi></bdi>)
```

nothing worked...

i've tried to adding the bdi with innerHTML to contenteditable div but the caret jumping to the start of contenteditable div and i still cant write inside the bdi tag.
basically what i try to do is to add bdi tag when pressing space button and write inside it in the current line.

my full code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenteditablediv" contenteditable="true"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
var contenteditable = document.getElementById("contenteditablediv");

contenteditable.onkeyup=function(event){
    if (event.keyCode==32) {
        contenteditable.innerHTML+='<bdi><bdi>'
    }
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can someone in here help me?